# VS2010 Load Test Failing - Cannot Open Database - NOT The Load Test Results database

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automated-tests, load-testing

Hi I have been battling with this issue all day.  I have a vs2010 load test which consists of three scenarios which are composed of three different web performance tests.

Each of the web performance tests select urls from a database which is configured correctly and runs locally.  However when the load test is run remotely it fails with the error:

Could not run load test 'Load Test' on agent 'AGENTSERVER'. Could not open the database 'URLSDB' requested by the login.  login failed for useraccount

In an attempt to get this working the agents and controller are set to run under a domain admin account, I can login to the database through Management Studio.  I've checked the connection string and can run the test locally but not remotely.  Does anyone have any ideas?  My next step is to set the connection string to the UrlsDB to use SQL Authentication

Comment: Have you tried logging into the database manually from your agent machine (e.g. with Management Studio or my favorite, LINQPad)? Maybe you can get a more useful error message that way. OTOH, I'll bet that SQL Authentication will probably work on the first try.

Comment: I can login successfully from the Agent Machines using SQL Authentication and Windows Authentication (Using account which is running the agent service) but cannot get my load test to run

Comment: Could you post your connection string (with sensitive parts redacted of course)? Maybe there is a clue there. You're not accidentally specifying localhost or '.' as the server name are you? Also, what about SQL Server logs, maybe there is a more helpful message there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to resolve it at 01:20AM.  When checking the datasources of  three individual tests which made up the mixes in the scenario, I found that the UI was showing that once one had been updated all three updated the connection string so that is why I was baffled as to why I was getting these errors, plus the error doesn't indicate which connection was having the issue.

So to eliminate the tests as being the issue I removed the datasource from each test and created individually named brand new datasources all till effectively pointing to the same sql server and the same database.  Then I ran the tests and all performed correctly, finally!!

So the core issue was the connection strings in the underlying tests were incorrect.  Will be testing the UI further to check if I was just my own error or there may actually be a bug in the UI, if I find a bug I'll report it.

Thanks to those who took the time to try to help me solve it, gutted that the issue was so minor when it had me baffled for nearly 20 hours :/

Answer (score 0):

The domain admin account you are running the test from cannot connect to the database server from the agent machine.

Log into the agent and debug the database connection from there.

Please be aware that a thread blocking call inside a web test, such as this may cause issues with your load test. I recommend that you load all test url's during the test instanciation if at all possible. 
Essentially minimise the database calls to as few as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I can login successfully using Management Studio and SQLCMD from the agent machine however my Load Test is still failing